# IIF Not like statement in Access 2007

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to make this QC display the reason for the file failing. The QC I have in place works great but when I try to give the reason all work with the exception of the invalid Zip Code. If the QC catches and error for any other reason is gives that reason as well as an invalid zip code. I have placed my reason logic below and pointed out the area I believe to have the issue.

```
Reason: IIf([CNMC Import.Gf_Date] Is Null,"No gift date, ","") & IIf([CNMC Import.Gf_Amount] Is Null,"No gift amount, ","") &
IIf([CNMC Import.Gf_CnBio_Key_Indicator] Is Null,"No individual or organization indicator, ","") &
IIf([CNMC Import.Gf_CnAdrSal_Addressee] Is Null,"No Addressee, ","") &
IIf([CNMC Import.Gf_CnAdrSal_Salutation] Is Null,"No Salutation, ","") &
IIf([CNMC Import.Gf_CnAdrPrf_Addrline1] Is Null,"No street address, ","") &
IIf([CNMC Import.Gf_CnAdrPrf_City] Is Null,"No city, ","") &
IIf([CNMC Import.Gf_CnAdrPrf_State] Is Null,"No state, ","") &
IIf([CNMC Import.Gf_CnAdrPrf_ZIP] Is Null,"No Zip Code, ","") & 
**IIf(([CNMC Import.Gf_CnAdrPrf_ZIP] Not Like "#####-####" & [CNMC Import.Gf_CnAdrPrf_ZIP]) Not Like "#####","Invalid zip code, ","")**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This (use a IIf 2 times):

```
IIf([CNMC Import.Gf_CnAdrPrf_ZIP] Like "#####-####", ",", IIf([CNMC Import.Gf_CnAdrPrf_ZIP]) Like "#####", ",", "Invalid zip code")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to combine two checks, then you cannot use the `&` sign which just merges strings together.

Instead of

```
IIf(([CNMC Import.Gf_CnAdrPrf_ZIP] Not Like "#####-####" & [CNMC Import.Gf_CnAdrPrf_ZIP]) Not Like "#####","Invalid zip code, ","")
```

try

```
IIf([CNMC Import.Gf_CnAdrPrf_ZIP] Not Like "#####-####" AND [CNMC Import.Gf_CnAdrPrf_ZIP] Not Like "#####","Invalid zip code, ","")
```

Comment: Returning the same results